# can't find Mac CMMI8 fonts for illustrator image create with python (postscript)

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, fonts, adobe-illustrator

I have illustrator in mac and in windows.
I have saved a figure as postscript with python matplotlib latex, when I try to open the figure with illustrator in windows it told me that I am missing the following fonts:

```
CMMI6
CMMI8
CMR8
CMSY8
```

I downloaded the fonts and installed them and everything worked.

When I tried to open the postscript with illustrator in **mac** , as expected it say that I need to install the fonts : CMMI6, CMMI8, CMR8, CMSY8.

but I did not managed to download and install the fonts.

I have tried to transfer the fonts from the windows system to the mac, but it was not able to.

This is the python code to create the postscript image

```
ipython —pylab

matplotlib.rcParams["text.usetex"] = True
# load the xfrac package
matplotlib.rcParams["text.latex.preamble"].append(r'\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}\usepackage{xfrac}')

figure()

plot([1,1],[2,3])
ylabel(r'\sfrac{$\tau_{peel}$}{$\tau_{m}$}')
draw()
show()
```

This is a link for an example postscript image that use the missing fonts. I am able to open it correctly on windows illustrator but I can not in **mac illustrator**.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uksyzkggr9lm5fr/test1.eps?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do with python but pylab. Unless you [customize](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fonts_demo.html) the fonts yourself but it will turn out to be more work. Your windows probably has those fonts installed already.

I suggest you just install the fonts and move on.

Comment: You suggest to install the fonts in mac right? I have tried but did not managed to find the correct ones..
If you have mac and illustrator, try to open the image.. try to install the correct fonts.. I did not managed..

Comment: Weird, it opened well. Not with illustrator but preview.